# MySQL loads CPU 100% for a minute with SELECT into SELECT

Tags: mysql

### Situation

My SQL query contains two parts. The first one is very simple:

```
SELECT * FROM `clients` WHERE id IN (...)
```

This one will return all information about clients with particular IDs

The second query is much larger, it should prepare the ID list for previous query (I omitted few more UNIONs for better readability, you can see full query at the end):

```
SELECT client_id
  FROM `contact_persons`
  WHERE id IN (
              SELECT owner_id
                FROM `contacts`
                WHERE contact_info LIKE '%keyword%' AND company_or_person = 'person'
  )
UNION
SELECT owner_id
  FROM `contacts`
  WHERE contact_info LIKE '%keyword%' AND company_or_person = 'company'
UNION
SELECT id
  FROM `clients`
  WHERE client_name LIKE '%keyword%'
```

Each of these queries takes less then 0.5 second to perform separately. But when I put the second query into the first one it makes both of them to take more than a minute to complete and CPU load jumps to 100% for this time.

### What did I try

- Run both parts of this query separately. Result: everything is fast enough (less then 0.5 second)
- Change the `SELECT * ...` to `SELECT id ...` (though it's makes whole query useless). Result: nothing changed
- Use few different keywords in order to avoid caching
- Make the inner part (large one) to return 0 rows. Result: nothing changed. The complete query is still terribly slow

It looks like if I run these parts of the query separately and store ID list in a php variable it will work fine, but it feels so wrong even for me as a beginner.

### Complete query

```
SELECT * FROM `clients` WHERE deleted = 0 AND id IN (
SELECT client_id as found
  FROM `contact_persons`
  WHERE id IN (
              SELECT owner_id
                FROM `contacts`
                WHERE contact_info LIKE '%keyword%' AND company_or_person = 'person'
 )
UNION
SELECT owner_id as found
  FROM `contacts`
  WHERE contact_info LIKE '%keyword%' AND company_or_person = 'company'
UNION
SELECT id as found
  FROM `clients`
  WHERE client_name LIKE '%keyword%'
UNION
SELECT client_id as found
  FROM `cargo`
  WHERE cargo_name LIKE '%keyword%'
UNION
SELECT page_id as found
  FROM `comments`
  WHERE message LIKE '%keyword%' AND page_type = 'client' AND deleted = 0
UNION
SELECT client_id as found
  FROM `contact_persons`
  WHERE person_name LIKE '%keyword%')
```

My database is very small (160 Kb) and in particular table `clients` have only 160 rows and 5 columns. I tried everything I could come up with but still couldn't solve the problem.

### Update 1. EXPLAIN

In the result of `EXPLAIN` I get
[image]

### Update 2. This is not about UNION

I just ran this minimal query where I cut off every part with `UNION`. Result: it took almost the same time - 57 seconds to perform

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id FROM `clients` WHERE id IN (
 SELECT client_id
   FROM `contact_persons`
   WHERE id IN (
               SELECT owner_id
                 FROM `contacts`
                 WHERE contact_info LIKE '%keyword%'
             )
)
```

### Update 3. Solution

As was suggested I tried to substitute one of the `IN` by `INNER JOIN` and this did the trick, ~60 seconds now turn to ~0.4s

So instead of

```
SELECT .. WHERE .. IN (SELECT .. WHERE .. IN (SELECT ..))
```

I wrote it like

```
SELECT .. AS t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT .. WHERE .. IN (SELECT ..)) AS t2 WHERE ti.id = t2.id
```

For a human it is pretty the same thing but looks like it is not for a MySQL server.

If somebody curious I post here `EXPLAIN` output for the final query:

[image]:

Comment: `LIKE '%keyword%'` is not SARGable, use [full-text index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html) instead.You can change `UNION` to `UNION ALL` to avoid sorting and removing duplicates if possible.

Comment: @lad2025 the part with `LIKE '%keyword%'` works fine, but I'll try

Comment: `LIKE '%keyword%'` may work but it won't utilize indexes

Comment: Please try fun both query without SQL cache

Comment: SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM TABLE

Comment: @zt1983811 the result is the same like when I used different keywords (I mentioned about it in the question). 0.4s for the large part and 60-65s for complete query. When I do use cash it take 0.0004s for the large part and 0.0005s for comlete query

Comment: change IN query to INNER JOIN. sometimes mysql optimizer not using index on IN clause.

Comment: Do you need to use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`? You could use the latter, potentially with a `SELECT DISTINCT` to later remove duplicates.

Comment: @siride even without any `UNION` at all the query is still very slow. See update 2 in the question

Comment: @huhushow looks like you're right, I substitute outer `IN` by `INNER JOIN`. It now 150 times faster (0.4s vs 60s), exactly like in case of separate queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is probably too complex and the query optimizer comes up with the wrong optimization. Running `EXPLAIN` against your query, as @huhushow suggested, will probably show this.

There are several approaches that you may try.

- The simpler is to run the queries separately, and accumulate all the ID's programmatically, then build the last query with the deduplicated list of ID's. This is what feels "wrong" to you. Indeed, with many more ID's retrieved, this approach may become awkward.
- A similar solution would be to accumulate the queries' results into a temporary table, using `INSERT IGNORE` and a unique index on `found` to ensure deduplication. Then you would run a JOIN between the clients table and the temporary table.
- A completely different approach would be to give more memory and time limits to the SQL query optimizer in order to encourage it to find a faster query plan. The difficulty here is in both intervening on mysqld's parameters (you might not be authorized to do so) and in the fact that altering the query later on might cause the optimizer to fail yet again; this solution, in other words, is not necessarily stable.
- Yet another approach would be to spread the outer SELECT inside the UNIONs, thus bringing the UNION out; i.e., instead of doing

  ```
  SELECT a.* WHERE id IN ( select1 UNION select2 UNION select3 )
  ```

  which is not easily optimizable due to the too many "degrees of separation" between where `id` is generated and where it is used, you would do first

  ```
  SELECT a.* WHERE id IN ( select1 )
  UNION
  SELECT a.* WHERE id IN ( select2 )
  UNION
  SELECT a.* WHERE id IN ( select3 )
  ```

  and then, in turn, you would merge the IN converting it into a JOIN. For example the first set:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM `clients` WHERE deleted = 0 AND id IN (
      SELECT client_id as found
      FROM `contact_persons`
      WHERE id IN (
        SELECT owner_id
          FROM `contacts`
          WHERE contact_info LIKE '%keyword%' AND company_or_person
          = 'person' )
  ```

  would become first:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM `clients` WHERE deleted = 0 AND id IN (
      SELECT cp.client_id as found
      FROM `contact_persons` AS cp
      JOIN `contacts` AS c ON (cp.id = c.owner_id)
          WHERE c.contact_info LIKE '%keyword%' AND c.company_or_person
          = 'person' )
  )
  ```

  and then finally a form which is easier on the optimizer:

  ```
  SELECT [DISTINCT] clients.* FROM `clients`
      JOIN `contact_persons` AS cp ON (clients.id = cp.client_id)
      JOIN `contacts` AS c ON (cp.id = c.owner_id)
           WHERE clients.deleted = 0 
           AND c.contact_info LIKE '%keyword%'
           AND c.company_or_person = 'person'
  ```

  As the very last stage you would add indexes: in the case above for example you're selecting `owner_id` from `contacts` based on `company_or_person` (which is an = criterion) and `contact_info`. You could therefore

  ```
  CREATE INDEX contacts_ndx_1 ON contacts(company_or_person, contact_info, owner_id)
  ```

  This also allows to perform all subqueries in their entirety, and see whether there is one of them that especially slows things down.

Comment: JOIN between the clients table and the temporary table - I'm not sure if I made it right but instead of outer `IN` I used `INNER JOIN` like this: `SELECT * FROM clients INNER JOIN (...large_query_from_question...)  AS list_of_id WHERE clients.deleted = 0 AND clients.id = list_of_id.found_id`. This query takes only 0.4s to perform and that's exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check Explain Query Plan of your query first. like this

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `clients` WHERE deleted = 0 AND id IN (
SELECT client_id as found
  FROM `contact_persons`
  WHERE id IN (
              SELECT owner_id
                FROM `contacts`
                WHERE contact_info LIKE '%keyword%' AND company_or_person = 'person'
 )
UNION
SELECT owner_id as found
  FROM `contacts`
  WHERE contact_info LIKE '%keyword%' AND company_or_person = 'company'
UNION
SELECT id as found
  FROM `clients`
  WHERE client_name LIKE '%keyword%'
UNION
SELECT client_id as found
  FROM `cargo`
  WHERE cargo_name LIKE '%keyword%'
UNION
SELECT page_id as found
  FROM `comments`
  WHERE message LIKE '%keyword%' AND page_type = 'client' AND deleted = 0
UNION
SELECT client_id as found
  FROM `contact_persons`
  WHERE person_name LIKE '%keyword%')
```

this can find out which part of your query is slow. 
[mysql official manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) is very helpful about understanding explain result.

Comment: I think my answer is not direct answer. but I think check query plan is first step of query optimization. and answers without plan is more like guess

Comment: Think about future readers searching for a solution as of why this may be happening. This is not a solution, this is merely a clue pointing out where to look for. __A good clue__, but not a real answer.

Comment: Many modern DBMS  perform a cost-based query optimization. That mean's there's no static solution. futher reader could do same thing. it could be right way. but it could be wrong way. I think it is more important, how to find slow part and fix it. my answer is about how to find slow part.

Comment: There's no static solution for just about __any__ case. I don't really understand why you mentioned it. Anyways, do whatever you like with your answers. It was my opinion, not a reason to start a debate.